# Python "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, modulenotfounderror

im working the first time with Python and want to rebuild the https://github.com/riffnshred/nhl-led-scoreboard to an nfl scoreboard (i know, there is a fantastic work on github, but i want to get all the great features the nhl script delivers with it).

My problem is, that my debugger says that the file "scoreboard_config.py" cannot found the "validate_json.py" at the nfl_setup directory.

My Tree is 1:1 like the nhl project, im only changed the names from nhl to nfl.

```
...
src/
   api/
   boards/
   config/
   data/
        -scoreboard_config.py
   images/
   nfl_api/ (old nhl_api)
   nfl_setup/ (old nhl_setup)
        -validate_json.py
   renderer/
   sbio/
...
```

My code at the scoreboard_config.py

```
from utils import get_file
from data.layout import Layout
from data.colors import Color
from config.main import Config
from nfl_setup.validate_json import validateConf 

# oldCode
# from nhl_setup.validate_json import validateConf 

import json
import os
import sys
import debug

...
```

So you can see, there is the same Project-Tree like the nhl Setup (where it's work perfect)...

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it by myself - i addet `__init__.py` to the nfl_source Directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).